# Performance tune PHP Time Query

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

I was wondering if I could do some performance tuning for the below PHP Script. What I am trying to do - is get every half hour from 00:00am to 23:30pm into a select list. Here is the code

```
<?php
$starttime = '00:00';
$time = new DateTime($starttime);
$interval = new DateInterval('PT30M');
$temptime = $time->format('H:i');
do{
   echo '<option value="">'.date("H:i a", strtotime($temptime)).'</option>';
   $time->add($interval);
   $temptime = $time->format('H:i');
}while ($temptime !== $starttime);
?>
```

I believe there is a way we can do it in an easier manner - but I cannot think of it. Can someone help?

Comment: You could hardcode them, because ... well, they doesn't change very often ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach (range(0, 60*24, 30) as $minutes) {
    echo '<option>' . date('H:i a', strtotime('00:00 +' . $minutes . ' minutes')) . '</option>';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Other than hardcoding the values, you can lose all the `DateTime` and `TimeInterval` objects and use a simple loop:

```
for ($h=0;$h<24;$h++) {
    echo '<option>' + sprintf ( "%02d", $h ) + ':00</option>';
    echo '<option>' + sprintf ( "%02d", $h ) + ':30</option>';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If performance is what you're after, hardcoding the time strings is probably the best thing you can do.

Since they won't change, you don't really need them dynamic, would you?

Comment: Just mentioned: You (the OP) can use your script to create the hardcoded list.

Answer (score 1):

Till day has 24h, you can use a good ol' `for`:

```
<select>
    <?php for($i = 0; $i < 48; $i++): ?>
        <option><?php echo $i%2 == 0 ? ($i / 2) . ':00' : intval($i / 2) .':30'; ?></option>
    <?php endfor;?>
</select>
```